# in Latex how to deal with @manual entry style (jabref)

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I've a problem so far unresolved and I have not found so much to help me in the different forums I've been looking to. Luckily somebody will have an answer :)
I have R software in my library .bib that I built under jabref and I want to cite the software in an article I'm writing with latex.
my reference entry in jabref is:

```
@MANUAL{R2012, 
title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing. Version
    2.15.1}, 
author = {{R Development Core Team}},  
year = {2012}, 
organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing}, 
address = {Vienna, Austria}, 
note = {{ISBN} 3-900051-07-0}, 
url = {http://www.R-project.org} 
}
```

when I try to cite R in my .tex file using `\citep*{R2012}`  (to get full author name) or just `\citep{R2012}` nothing happens. Does anyone know which mistake I can have done?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: ``citep`` is not a ``biblatex`` command, as far as I know. I suspect that the OP is new to bibliographies in LaTeX. If so, please have a look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management

Comment: So far, I tried compiling from TexShop but now from Sublime text 2 it is working. I guess the response is in the compiling sequence as you suggested because now it is working both way. Thanks for the response, it helps understanding how it is working!